# why can't I perform "GET" on nc, while I can browse to the site using web browser

Tags: apache-http-server, http

I host an apache http server on my laptop.

I put a text file in the web root: test.txt

I use firefox to browse to the site: http://192.168.0.100/test.txt

Everything runs smoothly, I can view the content of test.txt

but when I use nc and GET method as follow, I get error 408-request time out.

```
nc -nv 192.168.0.100 80
GET /test.txt HTTP/1.0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As specified in the [HTTP standard](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec5.html), you need to send two CRLF's, so after the `GET /test.txt HTTP/1.0` you need to press the enter key *twice*.